# How to use time command in bash, to sum sys + user time, and output it as milliseconds?

Tags: bash, time-command

The `time` command returns a table like this?

```
real      0m1.607s
user    0m0.154s
sys 0m0.032s
```

I am running this inside a shell script. What's the simplest way to process `time` output so that I get a variable `$RUNTIME` which holds the sum user + sys in milliseconds?

Comment: @l0b0 I'm not sure where to begin. I know how to sum two variables in bash, so if you teach me how to parse the output of `time` to get the two variables, `$sys` and `$user`, I can sum them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use bash `time` builtin function I'd use the following command:

```
a=$(echo $( TIMEFORMAT="%3U + %3S"; { time your_command; } 2>&1) "*1000" | bc -l)
```

Examples:

```
a=$(echo $( TIMEFORMAT="%3U + %3S"; { time sleep 1; } 2>&1) "*1000" | bc -l)
echo $a
2.000

a=$(echo $( TIMEFORMAT="%3U + %3S"; { time sudo hdparm -t -T /dev/sda 2>&1 >/dev/null; } 2>&1) "*1000"  | bc -l)
echo $a
2302.137
```

Comment: Is that in milliseconds? What if the command takes more than 1 second?

Comment: And how do I store the result in a variable?

Comment: I've updated my answer to store in a variable in ms

Comment: I'm aware this is askubuntu, but as a warning for folks like me: on macOS,
`echo "2.577 + 0.164 * 1000" | bc -l ` actually evaluates to `166.577`. You need to explicitly insert the parentheses around the sum in order to get the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do this

Run your command using below script, substitute `your_command`.

```
$ ALL_TIME=`(time your_command) 2>&1 | grep -E "user|sys" | sed s/[a-z]//g`
```

now variable ALL_TIME store two values: `

```
$ echo $ALL_TIME
00.001 00.003
```

Now you need to summarize values. Use script below

Don't forget to set **RUNTIME to zero**.

```
$ RUNTIME=0
$ for i in $ALL_TIME; do RUNTIME=`echo "$RUNTIME + $i"|bc`; done
$ echo $RUNTIME
.004
```

### Sources

[How to grep from time](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1876531)

[Redirect output of time command in unix into a variable in bash?](https://serverfault.com/questions/175376/redirect-output-of-time-command-in-unix-into-a-variable-in-bash)